# Can't mount Samba share - "No such device or address"

Tags: networking, mount, samba

I have a WiFi modem (`10.1.1.1`) running a Samba 1.0 file server (`SHARE`) and a USB flash drive connected to it. I am trying to mount the share directory to my existing local directory `/mnt/smb` using Arch Linux.

**Output of `smbclient -L //10.1.1.1 -U admin`:**

```
Sharename       Type      Comment
---------       ----      -------
SanDisk_SandiskUltra_1_fe6f Disk      
IPC$            IPC       IPC Service (Home Network Gateway)
Reconnecting with SMB1 for workgroup listing.

Server               Comment
---------            -------           
SHARE                Home Network Gateway

Workgroup            Master
---------            -------
WORKGROUP            SHARE
```

**Output of `sudo mount -t cifs //10.1.1.1/SHARE /mnt/smb -o username=admin,vers=1.0`**

```
Password for admin@//10.1.1.1/SHARE: 
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I think it is strange that I get `No such device or address` when clearly the location of the share directory is `10.1.1.1/SHARE` as confirmed by `smbclient`.

I am not sure what else I can do from here--any ideas?

Comment: Try vers=2.0 or even 3.0

Comment: You should access your share in the following manner: `//(SERVERNAME|IP)/SHARENAME`. What you currently seem to be doing is: `//IP/SERVERNAME`, which can't work. Try: `//10.1.1.1/SanDisk_SandiskUltra_1_fe6f`. This should mount the share `SanDisk_SandiskUltra_1_fe6f` on the server at `10.1.1.1`.

Comment: @rudib Thank you so much! That worked perfectly. If you leave an answer I will make it as accepted. :)

Comment: Glad it worked. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access your share in the following manner: `//(SERVERNAME|IP)/SHARENAME`.

What you currently seem to be doing is: `//IP/SERVERNAME`, which can't work.

Try: `sudo mount -t cifs //10.1.1.1/SanDisk_SandiskUltra_1_fe6f /mnt/smb -o username=admin,vers=1.0`.

This should mount the share `SanDisk_SandiskUltra_1_fe6f` on the server at `10.1.1.1`.

*Note*: If your name resolving service `nmbd` is set up correctly, you can also use `//SHARE/SanDisk_SandiskUltra_1_fe6f`. `SHARE` will be resolved to `10.1.1.1`.